# Software packages to run microphone frequency-response calibrations?

Tags: calibration, microphone, frequency-response

I will need to measure microphone frequency responses in the coming weeks. In the past I have always used scripts I wrote or written by colleagues. They seemed to work, but required tweaking each time as the scenario was slightly different (sweep playback, white noise playback). Also, some workflows involved correcting for the frequency response of the speaker too.

The ideal solution would be to use a software package which does 1) speaker frequency response correction, and 2) also calculates the frequency response of a given microphone. I'm using consumer grade mics (SMP-Knowles + SANKEN series) which are also ultrasound sensitive (despite tech specs from manufacturer, there is individual variation in response). I have access to ultrasound speakers and a calibration microphone too.

What does the BioAc community use to perform their calibrations? Can anyone suggest a software package that is out there which allows me to find the frequency response of my microphones in the ultrasound range?

*Background*: there are *many* 'calibration softwares' for the average audio/HiFi consumer found with a quick online search. However, they come with a 20 kHz cutoff, and the documentation isn't always clear on what they are doing exactly.

Comment: What does your input look like? Is it a series of recorded files or do you want the software to directly interface with the microphone/speaker?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any ready software package that can handle any configuration of AD-DA converters, amplifiers, speakers, and sensors. I would recommend to continue using custom software for this task. If you have a calibration microphone it should be straight forward to playing white noise and measure the response of the mic compared to the calibration mic. The effort needed is less in the software than in the buildup of the complete system with all components fitting together especially for cases outside the range of consumer audio. Hardware and Software from Avisoft or National Instruments could be suited for this task.